# Javascript: find all occurrences of word in text document

Tags: javascript, regex, string, indexof

I'm trying to write a Javascript function to find indices of all occurrences of a word in a text document. Currently this is what I have--

```
//function that finds all occurrences of string 'needle' in string 'haystack'
function getMatches(haystack, needle) {
  if(needle && haystack){
    var matches=[], ind=0, l=needle.length;
    var t = haystack.toLowerCase();
    var n = needle.toLowerCase();
    while (true) {
      ind = t.indexOf(n, ind);
      if (ind == -1) break;
      matches.push(ind);
      ind += l;
  }
  return matches;
}
```

However, this gives me a problem since this matches the occurrences of the word even when it's part of a string. For example, if the needle is "book" and haystack is "Tom wrote a book. The book's name is Facebook for dummies", the result is the index of 'book', 'book's' and 'Facebook', when I want only the index of 'book'. How can I accomplish this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to point out that regex has an "i" flag which causes the regular expression to match your string in a case-insensitive manner, so that there's no need for the `.toLowerCase()` calls above. I also saw it in some of the answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the regex I propose:

```
/\bbook\b((?!\W(?=\w))|(?=\s))/gi
```

To fix your problem. Try it with the `exec()` method. The regexp I provided will also consider words like "booklet" that occur in the example sentence you provided:

```
function getMatches(needle, haystack) {
    var myRe = new RegExp("\\b" + needle + "\\b((?!\\W(?=\\w))|(?=\\s))", "gi"),
        myArray, myResult = [];
    while ((myArray = myRe.exec(haystack)) !== null) {
        myResult.push(myArray.index);
    }
    return myResult;
}
```

**Edit**

I've edited the regexp to account for words like "booklet" as well. I've also reformatted my answer to be similar to your function.

You can do some testing [here](http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nasser. This looks pretty good. Do you know if there's a way to modify this to not just be restricted to single words but also multi-word phrases? For example, if I want to search for "book's name" it should give me all occurrences of "book's name" but not stuff like "book's name's".

Comment: Ah, the logic I used in that regexp is "Check if the word is followed by either 1. A non-word character which is followed by a word character or 2. a word character, and don't return those". This doesn't work for the "book's name" case, becasue it is followed by a space and a letter. I'll look into that and see.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getMatches(searchStr, str) {
    var ind = 0, searchStrL = searchStr.length;
    var index, matches = [];

    str = str.toLowerCase();
    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();

    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, ind)) > -1) {
         matches.push(index);
         ind = index + searchStrL;
    }
    return matches;
}
```

`indexOf` returns the position of the first occurrence of book.

```
var str = "Tom wrote a book. The book's name is Facebook for dummies";
var n = str.indexOf("book");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going on there but I can offer a better solution using a regex.

```
function getMatches(haystack, needle) {
    var regex = new RegExp(needle.toLowerCase(), 'g'),
        result = [];

    haystack = haystack.toLowerCase();

    while ((match = regex.exec(haystack)) != null) {
        result.push(match.index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
getMatches('hello hi hello hi hi hi hello hi hello john hi hi', 'hi');

Result => [6, 15, 18, 21, 30, 44, 47]
```

Conserning your `book` vs `books` problem, you just need to provide `"book "` with a space.

Or in the function you could do.

```
needle = ' ' + needle + ' ';
```

Comment: I can't just surround it with spaces because then it would miss the cases when a word ends a sentence. For example 'I read a book.' will miss the 'book'

Comment: @user2036311 Use this regex instead `var regex = new RegExp("\\b"+needle.toLowerCase()+"\\b(?!')",'g');`

Comment: Thanks for the new function but this does not seem to solve the problem that I do not want the index of "book's" but only of "book" i.e. whole word matches.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be using `text.match(RegX)` function. For example you can write something like this for a case insensitive search:

```
"This is a test. This is a Test.".match(/test/gi)
```

Result:

```
(2) ['test', 'Test']
```

Or this one for case sensitive scenarios:

```
"This is a test. This is a Test.".match(/test/g)
```

Result:

```
['test']
```

```js
let myControlValue=document.getElementById('myControl').innerText;
document.getElementById('searchResult').innerText=myControlValue.match(/test/gi)
```

```html
<p id='myControl'>This is a test. Just a Test
  </p>
  <span><b>Search Result:</b></span>
  <div id='searchResult'></div>
```